# Talend - tFileList loop through files load and move

Tags: etl, talend

I'm new to Talend and I'm having trouble with tidying up after I have looped through files and loading them to Postrgres.

The load works, and it moves all but one of the files. So if there are 5 files in the folder, it archives 4 and if there is one file it doesn't archive any. It always leaves one file left in the folder though and gives a permissions error.

I have tried various configurations of this job with and without the "tUnite", with a second loop (as shown) and just a move as part of the main job flow. File locking is the common theme across all of the different approaches I've used. This is the current error I get

*tFileCopy_1 C:\Users\stuar\Documents\vb-stock-20200705.csv -> C:\Users\stuar\Documents\Archive\vb-stock-20200705.csv: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.*

*C:\Users\stuar\Documents\vb-stock-20200705.csv tFileCopy_1 - The source file "C:\Users\stuar\Documents\vb-stock-20200705.csv" could not be removed from the folder because it is open or you only have read-only rights.**

Should I be spliting this into 2 jobs and calling them from a parent with load in one and the move in a separate job? or writing to a new file after the tUnite and loading the. It feels like the load is still hanging on to the file I am trying to move.

[image: Talend work flow]

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved it. I needed to

1. add in a tFileOutputDelimited in after the tUnite, which merges all the files into a new file
2. add in a tFileDelete at the end of my tPostJob to delete the staging file I created in the previous step

This all worked fine.

[image]